# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^3-\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3-\{b\}$, where $a\neq b$.

Tags: general-topology

**The Problem**: Prove that $\mathbb{R}^3-\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3-\{b\}$, where $a\neq b$.

**My Attempt**: I tried to use the Pasting Lemma by defining $f:\mathbb{R}^3-\{a, b\}\to\mathbb{R}^3-\{a, b\}$ as $f(x)=x$ and $g: \{a\}\to\{b\}$ as $g(a)=b$, which failed because $\mathbb{R}^3-\{a, b\}$ is not closed. This seems obvious, but I am somehow dead stuck-any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've overhyped this problem to yourself. It's not as tricky as it first appears!

To prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{b\}$, we should simply try to construct a homeomorphism between these two spaces.

That is, we want a continuous bijection $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}^3 - \{b\}$ whose inverse is also continuous.

Can you try to think of a continuous bijection $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}^3 - \{b\}$?

Comment: I supposed you meant $f(x, y, z)=(x-b_1+a_1, y-b_2+a_2, z-b_3+a_3)$, where $a=(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $b=(b_1, b_2, b_3)$?

Comment: That's the one! Well, actually, this one goes from $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{b\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{a\}$. But if you can convince yourself that this function and its inverse are both continuous, you'll be done!

Comment: Thank you so much!